# Save individual sheets as CSV and remove rows with specific text as a value

Tags: excel, vba, csv, rows

I have done my best to look through the whole site for an answer to this, but have not had any luck -or I don't know exactly what I am looking for.

My issue is that I have an XL workbook with 4 sheets; one that will hold raw data and the other three that will use VLookup to pull populate the sheets -This works fine. 
Now I run the VBA macro:

What the sheet should do is the following:

1: Take the contents of each sheet in the workbook and save each as a CSV
2: Run through A1:A1000 and if it finds the word NUKE then it will delete the entier row. 
3: Save the sheet again.

One of the things that may be getting in the way is that the data is being copied as formulas, but the save of the sheet is the values.

Edit: 
My apologies, I failed to mention the issue I was having. The rows are not deleting.

```
Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim SaveToDirectory As String, newName As String

    SaveToDirectory = "C:\jgd\"

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        newName = GetBookName(ThisWorkbook.Name) & "_" & WS.Name
        WS.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & newName, xlCSV
        Call RemoveRows
        ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True
    Next
    Call Msg_exe
End Sub

Function GetBookName(strwb As String) As String
    GetBookName = Left(strwb, (InStrRev(strwb, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
End Function

Sub CheckDir()

    Dim strPath  As String
    Dim lCtr     As Long

    strPath = "C:\jgd\"

    arrpath = Split(strPath, "\")
    strPath = arrpath(LBound(arrpath)) & "\"

    For lCtr = LBound(arrpath) + 1 To UBound(arrpath)
        strPath = strPath & arrpath(lCtr) & "\"
        If Dir(strPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            MkDir strPath
        End If
    Next
    Call SaveWorksheetsAsCsv
End Sub

Sub RemoveRows()

Dim i As Long
i = 1

Do While i <= ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Text, "NUKE", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop

End Sub
Sub Msg_exe()
    Dim Ret_type As Integer
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim strTitle As String
    strMsg = "Conversion is complete." & vbCrLf & "Do you want to open the destination folder?"
    strTitle = "Conversion Complete"
        Ret_type = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, strTitle)
        Select Case Ret_type
            Case 6
                Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "c:\jgd", vbNormalFocus)
        End Select
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you said there is an issue  .... and that's it. no mention of what it is ..... your row deletion code has a logic error .... if row 4 and row 5 both have NUKE .... you get to row 4 .... delete it  ..... then check row 5 (but it is what used to be row 6 before you deleted row 4)  .... original row 5 (with NUKE) is now row 4  .................... always do deletions backwards from end of sheet to top of sheet

Comment: @jsotola Thank you, your comment actually pointed me to my mistake and I was able to get it working.